# Is there a technology stack that makes connecting android applications easily?

Tags: java, android, web-applications

I'm creating an android application. Most of the functionality will be done offline, however I need to build some dependency between users of the application, such as being able to see peoples "high scores" and to communicate between users, and sending each other in-app messages.

Therefore, I'll need a webserver which the app can connect to in order to store such information. I imagine the app will make REST calls to get high scores.

I'm trying to avoid the overhead of having to create a fully functional web application (SpringMVC for example). Is there any application that makes this simpler?

What is a good, simple web stack I could use for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the Java [RESTlet framework](http://www.restlet.org/) for creating RESTful interfaces for our mobile apps, and deploy via [Google AppEngine](http://code.google.com/appengine/).  I shared a series of [screencasts on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=548C0D3986E5059A) demonstrating this approach that you might find useful.  The RESTlet framework used in the screencasts is a few versions old, but this should help you get up to speed fairly quickly.  We like this particular approach because it's straightforward for Android developers (who are already proficient in Java), scales well, and its free until you hit Google's quotas.